# Can I run mongo js scripts from reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Stack: Scala 2.11.8, ReactiveMongo 0.11.10, Playframework 2.4.6

We manage mongo update scripts through mongo scripts, which we manually apply on each update. I want to automate this process and make this part of startup process in Play, but it seems the only way to do this, is start writing scripts in Scala, using ReactiveMongo DSL.

Is there a way to use ReactiveMongo to send mongo scripts without rewriting them in ReactiveMongo terms?

**UPDATE**

Since it turned out, it's impossible to do it with Reactivemongo, I've just ran script from scala

```
    import sys.process._
    val mongoUpdateResult = "conf/mongo/update_mongo.sh" !!
```

Comment: You cannot execute MongoShell script, as they are specific to this client (not even to the wire protocol).

Comment: Thanks allot, can you add it as an answer, so I could mark this ticket as closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute MongoShell script, as they are specific to this client (not even to the wire protocol).